# Remote desktop printing via RDC through VPN connection using Laserjet Pro M1536dnf MFP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

I need to enable printing by 4 laptops to my local office LAN printer through Remote Desktop Connection(RDC) from my client’s system.  My printer is a HP Laserjet Pro M1536dnf MFP which is wireless. We use this printer to print from multiple client sites. Each laptop is able to print wirelessly to the printer. One of my key clients has setup for my office to print from an application on their system through RDC vis VPN connection using one of our laptops as a Print server. My client  has Windows server 2003. The issue is that the laptop has to always be on and in the office for the other staff to print, which is not feasible. I am trying to work with my client’s IT staff to change this. However, they want me to get a print server and a VPN network to enable printing, but this seems expensive, complicated and may impact my ability to print from other clients. Is there a simple way to enable the office to print to this printer without using the laptop as a go between?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://hplipopensource.com/ your printer is fully supporter on Linux, and even a raspberry pi 2  is capable enough to run a printing server what can be shared to every kind of client OS. It is very cheap, small and it has very low power consumption, and a noise far below human recognition.

You can use CUPS or SAMBA for your server.

You will need hplip package for your printer to work.

Sorry that I have not suggest some other alternative then a printing server, but it is very useful, extensible and on larger scale (maybe your clients and printers will grow in number) easier to manage.